# Create Panel with sidebar rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, twitter-bootstrap-3

Im new to rails. I need to create a panel for each company that is entered, Ideally similar to wordpress admin. Is there an example that can help me?

I need to create a sidebar that will change the content.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Muu1N.png)

Please help me, i'm new at this.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

There is a tutorial, how to create CMS in Rails from this page: 
https://pchm.co/posts/tutorial-how-to-build-a-cms-in-ruby-on-rails

The source code of the project:
https://github.com/pch/wellspring

On this screenshot below you can see how the final project will look like if you follow the tutorial:

[image]

I hope it helps for start.